# There are two identical directories in the Xcode project, but the same file is referenced. Why are there two?

Tags: xcode

There are two identical directories in the Xcode project, but the same file is referenced. Why are there two?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Looks like you've added the same project twice to the same workspace.

Answer (score 0):

There are two projects in the same workspace. If you delete one of the `HM`projects by `right-clicking`, selecting `delete`, and select `Remove Reference` the repeated project will disappear and you won't have any issues.